# How to use the command LOCATE in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function

I want to use the command LOCATE  to search, but I do not know how to put it inside the code to work. Please help me if you know the answer

```
  $obj = AdsPublic::with('getFile')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'adspublic.owner_id')
        ->when(isset($request->adspublic_title), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->orWhere(DB::raw("LOCATE('.$request->adspublic_title.',adspublic.adspublic_title)"));

        })->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
$query->where('adspublic.adspublic_title', 'like', '%'.$request->adspublic_title.'%');
```

Comment: Do you want to search, for example, if 'sh' available in 'fish'?

Comment: The command I want to use works more accurately in the search

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the position of the search word or if it's available in the title column?